# How to I convert multiple Pandas DFs into a single Spark DF?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have several Excel files that I need to load and pre-process before loading them into a Spark DF.  I have a list of these files that need to be processed.  I do something like this to read them in:

```
file_list_rdd = sc.emptyRDD()

for file_path in file_list:
    current_file_rdd = sc.binaryFiles(file_path)
    print(current_file_rdd.count())
    file_list_rdd = file_list_rdd.union(current_file_rdd)
```

I then have some mapper function that turns `file_list_rdd` from a set of (path, bytes) tuples to (path, Pandas DataFrame) tuples.  This allows me to use Pandas to read the Excel file and to manipulate the files so that they're uniform before making them into a Spark DataFrame.

How do I take an RDD of (file path, Pandas DF) tuples and turn it into a single Spark DF?  I'm aware of functions that can do a single transformation, but not one that can do several.

My first attempt was something like this:

```
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)

def convert_pd_df_to_spark_df(item):
    return sqlCtx.createDataFrame(item[0][1])

processed_excel_rdd.map(convert_pd_df_to_spark_df)
```

I'm guessing that didn't work because `sqlCtx` isn't distributed with the computation (it's a guess because the stack trace doesn't make much sense to me).

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read :).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm being given thousands of Excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by writing a function like this:

```
def pd_df_to_row(rdd_row):
    key = rdd_row[0]
    pd_df = rdd_row[1]        

    rows = list()
    for index, series in pd_df.iterrows():
        # Takes a row of a df, exports it as a dict, and then passes an unpacked-dict into the Row constructor

        row_dict = {str(k):v for k,v in series.to_dict().items()}
        rows.append(Row(**row_dict))

    return rows
```

You can invoke it by calling something like:

```
processed_excel_rdd = processed_excel_rdd.flatMap(pd_df_to_row)
```

`pd_df_to_row` now has a collection of Spark `Row` objects.  You can now say:

```
processed_excel_rdd.toDF()
```

There's probably something more efficient than the `Series`-> `dict`-> `Row` operation, but this got me through.

Answer (score 3):

Can be done using conversion to Arrow RecordBatches which Spark > 2.3 can process into a DF in a very efficient manner.

https://gist.github.com/linar-jether/7dd61ed6fa89098ab9c58a1ab428b2b5

This snippet monkey-patches spark to include a `createFromPandasDataframesRDD` method.
The `createFromPandasDataframesRDD` method accepts a RDD object of pandas DFs (Assumes same columns) and returns a single Spark DF.

Comment: As of Apache Spark 3.4/3.5, `arrowPayloadToDataFrame` (or `toDataFrame`) not longer seems to exist. Is it known how to do this in the most recent versions of pySpark?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a list of the dataframes or filenames and then call union in a loop. Something like this:

If pandas dataframes:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
sdf = None
for df in dfs:
    if sdf:
        sdf = sdf.union(spark.createDataFrame(df))
    else:
        sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

If filenames:

```
names = [name1, name2, name3, name4]
sdf = None
for name in names:
    if sdf:
        sdf = sdf.union(spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_excel(name))
    else:
        sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_excel(name))
```

Comment: If I have thousands of Excel files, this will be slow. The goal on the beginning of my approach was to try to leverage Spark's parallelization. If I could do this in a for loop, I wouldn't need Spark at all.  In my case, several gigabytes of Excel data.

Comment: @zero323 calling `flatMap(lambda x: x[1].values)` on the`processed_excel_rdd` gives me a bunch of nd_array objects as expected.  Calling `toDF` on an RDD full of nd_array objects results in this stack trace:  https://pastebin.com/nX4gkXvg