# Create Spark DataFrame from Pandas DataFrames inside RDD

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to convert a Pandas DataFrame on each worker node (an RDD where each element is a Pandas DataFrame) into a Spark DataFrame across all worker nodes.

Example:

```
def read_file_and_process_with_pandas(filename):
    data = pd.read(filename)
    """
    some additional operations using pandas functionality
    here the data is a pandas dataframe, and I am using some datetime
    indexing which isn't available for spark dataframes
    """
    return data

filelist = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']
rdd = sc.parallelize(filelist)
rdd = rdd.map(read_file_and_process_with_pandas)
```

The previous operations work, so I have an RDD of Pandas DataFrames. How can I convert this then into a Spark DataFrame after I'm done with the Pandas processing?

I tried doing `rdd = rdd.map(spark.createDataFrame)`, but when I do something like `rdd.take(5)`, i get the following error:

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o103.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there a way to convert Pandas DataFrames in each worker node into a distributed DataFrame?

Comment: You want an `rdd` of spark DataFrames? I don't think that's possible. Why are you trying to do this? What's the end goal?

Comment: Which version of your spark ?

Comment: I need to use Panda's datetime indexing, which isn't possible with spark RDDs or dataframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231046/7964197

I've had to deal with the same problem, which seems quite common (reading many files using pandas, e.g. excel/pickle/any other non-spark format, and converting the resulting RDD into a spark dataframe)

The supplied code adds a new method on the `SparkSession` that uses `pyarrow` to convert the `pd.DataFrame` objects into arrow record batches which are then directly converted to a `pyspark.DataFrame` object

```
spark_df = spark.createFromPandasDataframesRDD(prdd) # prdd is an RDD of pd.DataFrame objects
```

For large amounts of data, this is orders of magnitude faster than converting to an RDD of Row() objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think this is a pretty common problem when you need to use the datetime indexing powers of pandas. It would be great if spark could natively handle the conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas dataframes can not direct convert to rdd. 
You can create a Spark DataFrame from Pandas

```
spark_df = context.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

Reference: [Introducing DataFrames in Apache Spark for Large Scale Data Science](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html)

Comment: I already tried this, you can see in my answer. This isn't really what i'm looking for, i'm trying to map a pandas dataframe which is in an RDD on each worker node into a spark dataframe across all nodes.

Comment: Ok~ In that case , I think you better write some UDF , and put panda in your UDF.