# How can I convert a PySpark RDD of Pandas DataFrame objects into a single Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have a PySpark RDD where each row is a Pandas object and I need to get a single dataframe result.

This is similar to the following questions already answered, but the accepted solutions use PySpark functionalities only available in the older version (3.0.0)

[GitHub solution for older version](https://gist.github.com/linar-jether/7dd61ed6fa89098ab9c58a1ab428b2b5)

[StackOverflow Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453268/create-spark-dataframe-from-pandas-dataframes-inside-rdd)

[StackOverflow Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457596/how-to-i-convert-multiple-pandas-dfs-into-a-single-spark-df/51231046#51231046)

Calling dataframe conversion with

```
RDD.toDF()
```

directly results in an error. Truth value of dataframe is ambiguous.

This is operational with collecting all the rows of the RDD with

```
 rdd.collect()
```

but that is very slow and calls back all the data to one driver.

Calling the spark dataframe conversion on each dataframe within the RDD with

```
 .toDF()
```

also does not work because of a marge type error between doubles and strings, so I have to pass the Pandas dataframes with

```
.astype(str)
```

which is very slow.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `Calling the spark dataframe conversion on each dataframe within the RDD with .toDF()` - the elements within the RDD are not RDDs and, thus, `.toDF()` on each of them will result in an error.

Comment: @samkart but they are pandas dataframes, and based on documentation that should work on a pandas dataframe

Comment: pandas dataframes don't have any `toDF()` method. Do they?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to create spark dataframes, but *[full disclosure]* I'm guessing this method would also be slow.

Use a `reduce()` with `pd.concat()` to return a pandas dataframe and then use `createDataFrame()` on the result to create a spark dataframe.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([pdf1, pdf2, pdf3, pdf4]).
    reduce(lambda x, y: pd.concat([x, y]))
```

The aforementioned will return a single pandas dataframe with all individual dataframes appended. Use a `createDataFrame()` on it to get spark dataframe.

```
spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize([pdf1, pdf2, pdf3, pdf4]).
    reduce(lambda x, y: pd.concat([x, y]))
)
```

The aforementioned will create a spark dataframe using the result of the `RDD.reduce()` which will return a pandas dataframe.